# JSFiddle and Chrome Inspector

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jsfiddle, web-inspector

I'm currently inspecting a fiddle on JSFiddle with Google Chrome and it seems that I cannot get the current element selected in "Elements" tab, which normally would be retrieved with $0

Also, it seems that jQuery is not available. In the console it says that jQuery is not defined.

Any idea on how to solve these problems?

Comment: Post the fiddle you are working on.

Comment: There's no need. See the answer below, because it answers the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the `top frame` dropdown to `jsFiddle result`. Like in this image : [image]